# How to create a script for SQL Server database create / upgrade from any state

Tags: sql-server

I need to create scripts for creating or updating a database. The scripts are created from my test Database or from my source control.

The script needs to upgrade a database from any version of my application to the current version so it needs to be agnostic to what already exists in the database.

I do not have access to the databases that will be upgraded.

e.g.

- If a table does not exist the script should create it.
- If the table exists the script should check if all the columns exist (And check their types).

I wrote a lot of this checking code in C# as in i have an SQL create table script and the C# code checks if the table (and columns) exists before running the script.

My code is not production ready and i wanted to know what ready made solutions are out there.

Comment: In the future, will your 'upgrade' tool chain be in control of the schema? Or is there a chance some creative sysadmin will start tinkering with the database model? In other words, how much abuse must this upgrader be able to withstand, and does that apply only to legacy databases, or do you expect ongoing surprises?

Comment: It seems you are searching for [State based](https://samirbehara.com/2018/04/16/database-delivery-state-based-vs-migration-based/) migration approach like for  instance SSDT. You develop your DB project locally, and during deployment time you allow the schema compare tool to generate SQL difference script - which should be revised and deployed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about Schema state, you can look at state-based deployment-tools instead of change-based. (not the official terminology)

You should look at these two tools

- SQL Server Data Tools (Dacpac) [data-tier-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?view=sql-server-ver15) *which is practically free*
- RedGate has an entire toolset for this https://www.red-gate.com/solutions/need/automate. *which is licensed*

The one thing to keep in mind with State based deployments is that you don't control how the database gets from one-state to another, with SSDT

For example a column-rename = drop and recreate that column, same for a table-rename.

In their defence they do have some protections and do tell you what is about to happen.

**EDIT (Updating to address comment below)**

It should not be a problem that you can't access the TargetDb while in development. You can still use the above tools *provided* you can use them (Dacpac/Redgate) tooling when you are deploying to the TargetDb.

> If you are hoping to have a dynamic TSQL script that can update a target database in an unknown state. Then that is a recipe for failure/disaster. *I do have some suggestions at the end for dealing with this*.

The way I see it working is

1. Do your development using Dacpac/Redgate
2. Build your artefacts Dacpac / Redgate package
3. Copy artefact to the deployment server with tools
4. when doing deployments use the tools ([Dacpac Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/deploy-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-ver15#powershell-examples)) or [Redgate manually](https://documentation.red-gate.com/dlma1/tutorials/using-the-powershell-cmdlets/deploy-a-database-package-manually)

If your only choice is a TSQL script, then the only option is extensive-defensive coding covering all possibilities.

1. Every object must have an existence check
2. Every property must have a state check
3. Every object/property must have a roll forward / roll backward script.

For example to sync a table

1. A Script to check the table exists, if not create it
2. A script to check each property of the table is in the correct state
3. check all columns and their data-types and script to update them to match
4. check defaults
5. check indexes, partitioning etc

Even with this, you might not be able to handle every scenario.

Comment: From what i can see these tools require a target DB.
The problem is i do not have access to the target DB.
I need my script to work on multiple DB that could all be in different states.

Comment: FWIW, the terminology I see most often used to describe these strategies are "model-based" versus "migration scripts" deployments. Developing idempotent (re-runnable) scripts manually is non-trivial in complex scenarios with dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with frameworks that can do this.
Such an inquiry is off-topic for SO anyway.
But depending on your demands, it may not be too hard to implement something yourself.

One straightforward approach would be to work with incremental schema changes; basically just a chronological list of SQL scripts.
Never change or delete existing script (unless something really bad is in there).
Instead, just keep adding upgrade scripts for every new version.

**Yes**, 15 years later you will have accumulated 5,000 scripts.
Trust me, it will be the least of your problems.

To create a new database, just execute the full chain of scripts in chronological order.
For upgrades, there are two possibilities.

1. Keep a progress list in every database.
   That is basically just a table containing the names of all scripts that have already been executed there.
   To upgrade, just execute every script that is not in that list already. Add them to the list as you go.
   **Note:** if necessary, this can be done with one or more auto-generated, deployable, static T-SQL scripts.
2. Make every script itself responsible for recognizing whether or not it needs to do anything.
   For example, a 'create table' script checks if the table already exists.

I would recommend a combination of the two:

- option #1 for new versions (as it scales a lot better than #2)
- option #2 for existing versions (as it may be hard to introduce #1 retroactively on legacy production databases)

Depending on how much effort you will put in your upgrade scripts, the 'option #2' part may be able to fix some schema issues in any given database.
In other words, make sure you start off with scripts that are capable of bringing messy legacy databases back in line with the schema dictated by your application.
Future scripts (the 'option #1' part) have less to worry about; they should trust the work done by those early scripts.

No, this approach is *not* resistant against outside interference, like a rogue sysadmin.
It will not magically fix a messed-up schema.
It's an illusion to think you can do that automatically, without somebody analyzing the problem.
Even if you have a tool that will recreate every missing column and table, that will not bring back the data that used to be in there.
And if you are not interested in recovering data, then you might as well discard (part of) the database and start from scratch.

On the other hand, I would recommend to make the upgrade scripts 'idempotent'.
Running it once or running it twice should make no difference.
For example, use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` rather than `DROP TABLE`; the latter will throw an exception when executed again.
That way, in desperate times you may still be able to repair a database semi-automatically, simply by re-running everything.

Answer (score 0):

The work you are trying to do requires you start using a standard change control process.

Given the risk of data loss, and issues related to creation of columns in a specific sequence and the potential for column definitions to change.

I recommend you look at defining a base line version which you will manually have to upgrade each system to.

You can roll your own code, and use a schema version table, or use any one of the tools available such as redgate sql source control, visual studio database projects, dbup, or others.

I do not believe any tool will bring you from 0-1, however, once you baseline, any one of these tools will greatly facilitate your workflow.

Start with this article [Get Your Database Under Version Control](https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/)

Here are some tools that can help you?

[Octopus Schema Migrations](https://octopus.com/database-migrations)

[Flyway By Redgate](https://flywaydb.org/)

[Idera Database Change Management](https://www.idera.com/database-change-management)

[SQL Server Data Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/)